# 2-D dynamic array of Base and Derived classes

Tags: c++

I'm declaring a 2-D dynamic array of Base class. Some of these dynamic objects are being declared as objects of Derived class. The constructor of the Derived class is being called on, but the object of Derived class is not calling on the correct virtual function

Organism is Base class
Ant is Derived class

Organism.cpp

```
Organism::Organism(){//default constructor
    occupy = false;
    mark = '_';
}
Organism::Organism(int){//constructor called on by the Ant constructor
    occupy = true;
}
char Organism::getMark(){//Used to make sure the Ant constructor is properly called
    return mark;
}
virtual void yell(){//virtual function
        cout << "organism" << endl;
    }
```

Ants.cpp

```
Ant::Ant() : Organism(){}//not really used
Ant::Ant(int) : Organism(5){//initialize the Ant object
    setMark('O');//mark
    antsNum++;
}
void yell(){//override the virtual function 
        cout << "ant" << endl; 
    }
```

main.cpp

```
Organism **grid = new Organism*[20];
char c;
    ifstream input("data.txt");//file contains data

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

        grid[i] = new Organism[20];//initialize the 2d array

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            input >> c;//the file has *, X, O as marks

            if (c == '*'){
                grid[i][j] = Organism();//call on the default constructor to mark it as _
            }
            else if (c == 'X'){
                grid[i][j] = Doodle(5);
            }
            else if (c == 'O'){
                grid[i][j] = Ant(5);
            }
        }
    }
//out of the loop

cout << grid[1][0].getMark() << endl;//outputs 'O', meaning it called on the ant constructor
    grid[1][0].yell();//outputs organism, it is not calling on the Ant definition of the function yell()
```

I do understand that all the array is of type Organism, not of type Ant, how do I change that?

Comment: Have a matrix of *pointers* to the base-type? And is there a reason you're not using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: I really don't like vectors, and then I have to use other functions that will will have to move, destroy and breed other objects. Will try vectors later I guess.

Comment: Using the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), including its [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)  will make your life as a C++ programmer so much easier  and pleasant in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your array as pointer to pointer to pointer:

```
Organism ***grid = new Organism**[20];
```

The matrix now holds pointers to Organism. The way you did it you are initializing an Organism with Doodle instead of having an Organism be a Doodle.

You should have:

```
grid[i][j] = new Doodle(5);
```

Right now what is happening is Organisms copy constructor is being called so you are actually storing Organisms instead of pointers to derived types.

An even better way of doing it is to use boost::matrix:

```
boost::matrix<Organism *> m(20, 20);
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Organism>>> grid` is even better.

Comment: @Jarod42 A bit. Nested `std::vectors` still aren't a good solution.

Comment: Depends for what. I don't like using vectors to represent matrices because no one guarantees that all the vectors will be of the same length. Maybe use boost::matrix

Comment: @Jarod42 Since the since seems to be know at compile time : `std::array` might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You have [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) here.

There are twenty `Organisms` created:

```
grid[i] = new Organism[20];//initialize the 2d array
```

And then, you try to copy a temporary `Ant` into the `Organism` at `[i][j]`:

```
grid[i][j] = Ant(5);
```

but this doesn't work.

Remove the first line (initialize..), and replace the second line with

```
grid[i][j] = new Ant(5);
```

and likewise for the `Organism` and `Doodle`.